# Asymptotic probability of prime divisors

Tags: asymptotics, primality-test

I was curious about methods of finding primes. One method is to keep a list of the first $n$ primes, then check if the input modulo any prime less than its square root is zero. If none of those primes is a divisor, check all odd numbers between the greatest prime and the square root of the input for a factor.

Assuming the input is a random integer, I figured I could see how often this method finds a factor among the first $n$ primes.

Let $P_n$ be the set of the first $n$ primes. The asymptotic probability that a random input will have a factor among the first $n$ primes is:

$$k_n=1+\sum_{A\subseteq P_n}\dfrac{(-1)^{|A|+1}}{\displaystyle \prod_{a\in A}a}$$

Calculating the first few of these:

$$k_2=\dfrac{1}{2} \\ k_3=\dfrac{2}{3} \\ k_4=\dfrac{11}{15} \\ k_5=\dfrac{27}{35} \\ k_6=\dfrac{61}{77}$$

I'm sure this sequence is known, but it is not an integer sequence, and it was not found on Wolframalpha. Does this sequence have a name? I'm not sure how to look it up to find out more about it.

Comment: You seem to mean the probability that a random number has no prime divisor below some positive integer $x$. This probability is asymptotically (if $x\rightarrow \infty$) $\frac{e^{-\gamma}}{\ln(x)}$ , where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant. Unfortunately , sieving out small factors has no significant effect , if you want to find huge primes, so this is still a challange.

Comment: For more details, google rough numbers.

Comment: The original problem was, given a list of random positive integers, return a list of the primes. So, in reality, I only have to consider numbers in the range of $1$ to $2^{32}-1$. So, while I am looking for primes, I'm kinda also looking to get lucky with my list of integers and chug through it quickly. So, I want to choose a number of primes to sieve out to give me a decent probability that I discovered a factor.

Comment: That said, it is more beneficial for me to focus on the probability that a prime is a factor than look at a single number and figure out the probability that none of the numbers in my sieve are factors.

Comment: I just guessed 20 primes would be enough. I combined that with your advice. It is relatively quick to check the first twenty primes, and they rule out some $87\%$ of all primes. If that doesn't work, then I can try a more sophisticated primality test. Even that might be too many. I can probably use two primes (just 2 and 3) and that would be good enough to weed out the bulk of the results.